# Is Apache Spark appropriate for generic non-analytics OLTP tasks.

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am looking into getting into Apache Spark to use with a cassandra database with scala and Akka and I ahve been trying to find the answer to the question of whether i could actually drop my existing Cassandra driver and use Spark exclusively. Does it have means to find records by partition keys and so on or can it only take the entire table and filter it. I knoe you could filter to a single record but that means iterating through a potentially massive table. I want spart to essentially issue CQL where clauses and allow me to fetch only a single row if I choose or a set of rows. If this is not possible then I need to stick with my existing driver for the normal db operations and spark for the analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible to issue CQL where clause in Spark with CassandraRDD.where()**

> To filter rows, you can use the filter transformation provided by Spark. However, this approach causes all rows to be fetched from Cassandra and then filtered by Spark. Also, some CPU cycles are wasted serializing and deserializing objects that wouldn't be included in the result. To avoid this overhead, CassandraRDD offers the where method, which lets you pass arbitrary CQL condition(s) to filter the row set on the serve

Here is a simple example on how to use CassandraRDD.where()

If you have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test.data (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   data text
);
```

You can use spark to select and filter with primary key.

```
sc.cassandraTable("test", "data ").select("id", "data").where("id = ?", 1).toArray.foreach(println)
```

More on : https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md

But In Cassandra driver you have more flexibility and control over your query and also Spark will cost you more cpu, time and memory than the cassandra driver.

As RussS Says

> "While this is correct and the where clause allows you to run a single partition request, This is orders of magnitude more expensive than running analogous queries directly through the Java Driver"

Comment: This could be the right answer, thanks. Wondering if there is any caveats. If this works out I'd like to use Spark as my primary cassandra connector manager.

Comment: While this is correct and the where clause allows you to run a single partition request, This is orders of magnitude more expensive than running analogous queries directly through the Java Driver.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as the answer. I will use the base drive for OLTP and spark for RDD stuff.